# Different types of magnetic exchange

Tags: quantum-mechanics, identical-particles, ferromagnetism, exchange-interaction

I am a bit confused about the mechanisms of different types of exchange. Mainly, I am trying to understand mechanisms that lead to magnetic ordering and I came across several different types of exchange:

1. Direct exchange
2. Double exchange
3. Super-exchange

I understand that the term 'exchange interaction' is vested in the antisymmetric nature of the fermion - This sort of exchange is usually an interplay between Coulombic interaction and Pauli's exclusion principle. **Is this what 'Direct exchange' actually refers to?**

I also know that super-exchange is related to hopping of electrons between M-O-M systems (Metal-oxygen-Metal) where it can lead to ferromagnetic or antiferromagnetic order depending upon the orientation of the orbitals etc. This is further dictated by the well-known Goodenough-Kanamori rules.

Please correct me if my assessment is wrong, any help in resolving this would be much appreciated.

Comment: For a start, [Simple description of exchange interaction?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/18395/37364)