# Question About Exchange

Tags: condensed-matter, exchange-interaction

Is the Exchange term, for example in a set of Hartree-Fock equations for a solid, to be interpreted as arising from electrons actually, physically, exchanging positions constantly?

So, for a metal, I can think of the conduction electrons as correlating their motions based upon the positions of all of the other conduction electrons, AND, also constantly exchanging positions with other conduction electrons?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Possibly of interest: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/648950/

Comment: Thanks @Andrew !  That is a good post to read.  I do note that the same question was asked, but not specifically answered.  Thanks again.