# Is exchange interaction just a consequence of approimations?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, many-body, exchange-interaction

My background is in molecular physics, and I have encountered the term 'exchange interaction' in this context first, but it seems to be used in many areas of physics.

In my understanding, seems to be confirmed by [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/18395/simple-description-of-exchange-interaction) or the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchange_interaction), exchange interaction is defined as the energy difference between exchanging two particles in the total wavefunction defined by one-particle orbitals. For example if we assume that the helium atom has the wavefunction (with proper normalization and antisymmetrization ensured by the operator $\hat{A}$)

$$ \Psi = \hat{A} [\psi_A(r_1) \psi_B(r_2)] \; , $$

then the total energy will have Coulomb $J$ and exchange $K$ contributions of the form

$$ J = \int \frac{(\psi_A(r_1) \psi_B(r_2))^2}{r_{12}} \;  $$

$$ K = \int \frac{\psi_A(r_1) \psi_B(r_2) \psi_A(r_2) \psi_B(r_1) }{r_{12}} \; , $$

respectively, with $K$ called exchange due to the exchange of the electrons in the orbitals.

The full wavefunction $\Psi(r_1,r_2)$ will, of course, not be exactly factored into one-particle contributions, so the integrals $J$ and $K$ will not be defined as they have been above, and the total energy will just be $\langle \Psi|\hat{H}|\Psi\rangle $ without any specific contributions arising naturally.

My question is then: does it make sense to talk about exchange interaction in such cases? Does exchange interaction only arise from our assumption of one-particle orbitals, or is it somehow a fundamental concept of nature, defined even if the exact many-body wavefunction is known?

Comment: I will wait for more in-depth answers, but I think a better way of looking at it might be a constraint. Other types of artifacts that arise from constraints are 'normal forces'. In some cases one can express the problem in such a way that constraint is respected implicitly, sometimes it is more convenient to have it explicitly (e.g. [Lagrange multipier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier))